# Qt: Replacing deprecated pos() methods

Tags: python, qt

I have a simple app (a piano keyboard which receives midi and shows which keys are pressed)  with a frameless window that I can drag around with the left mouse button.

This works:

```py
  def mousePressEvent(self,e):
    modifiers = e.modifiers()
    if modifiers == Qt.ControlModifier:
      app.quit()
    else:
      self.mpos = e.pos()
  def mouseMoveEvent(self,e):
    buttons = e.buttons()
    if buttons == Qt.LeftButton:
      dpos = e.pos() - self.mpos
      newpos = self.pos() + dpos
      self.move(newpos)
```

But `pos()` is deprecated and I can't figure out what to replace it with.

Answer (score -1):

It seems you use `.position()` on the mouse event (not `.globalPosition()`) and `.pos()` on a widget is *not* deprecated whereas `.pos()` on an event *is* deprecated.

```py
  def mousePressEvent(self,e):
    modifiers = e.modifiers()
    if modifiers == Qt.ControlModifier:
      app.quit()
    else:
      self.mpos = e.position()
  def mouseMoveEvent(self,e):
    buttons = e.buttons()
    if buttons == Qt.LeftButton:
      dpos = e.position() - self.mpos
      dpos = dpos.toPoint()
      newpos = self.pos() + dpos
      self.move(newpos)
```